# Error Parsing JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I try to parse [this json file](https://pastebin.com/raw/TTuV7K7J) to get all the directions values listed using PHP :

I don't know why my code doens't work :

```
$json_source = file_get_contents('https://pastebin.com/raw/TTuV7K7J');
$data = json_decode($json_source);
foreach ($data->departures as $a) {
    foreach ($a->display_informations as $b) {
        echo $b->direction . '<br />';
    }
}
```

I keep having this error :

> Trying to get property of non-object

The `echo` is the line causing the code to crash. When I display a `var_dump($b)` I got the following for each JSON entry:

```
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string 'Versailles-Chantiers (Versailles)' (length=33)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string 'N' (length=1)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string 'SNCF' (length=4)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string '00A092' (length=6)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string 'Paris-Montparnasse 1-2 - Versailles-Chantiers' (length=45)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string 'Train de banlieue / RER' (length=23)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string '164273' (length=6)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string 'N' (length=1)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string '' (length=0)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string 'Transilien' (length=10)
C:\wamp64\www\index.php:10:string '' (length=0)
```

Here is what the json looks like :

```
{
"pagination":{},
"links":[],
"disruptions":[],
"notes":[],
"feed_publishers":[],
"departures":[
          {
          "display_informations":{
                    "direction":"Versailles-Chantiers (Versailles)",
                    "code":"N",
                    "network":"SNCF",
                    "links":[],
                    "color":"00A092",
                    "name":"Paris-Montparnasse 1-2 - Versailles-Chantiers",
                    "physical_mode":"Train de banlieue \/ RER",
                    "headsign":"164273",
                    "label":"N",
                    "equipments":[],
                    "text_color":"",
                    "commercial_mode":"Transilien",
                    "description":""
          },
          "stop_point":{},
          "route":{},
          "links":[],
         "stop_date_time":{}
         },
         {...},
         {...},
],
"context":{},
"exceptions":[]
}
```

How am I supposed to do to get the `direction` value ?

Comment: Which line does the error refer to? Have you tried some simple debugging and `var_dump`ed the offending variable to see what it is you're trying to access a property on?

Comment: I updated my post. I still can't figure out why it doesn't work tho.

Comment: `display_informations` is not an array, you don't need to loop through it.

Comment: The error message is crystal clear. "Trying to get property of non-object". `$b` is not an object, hence `->direction` fails. You even var dumped the variable, which told you that they were strings! You need to ***read*** what is being outputted :)

Comment: I managed to get it to work finally. As I am not a developer that wasn't that obvious to me, I'm learning  ;)